# Overriding abstract method using anonymous class

Tags: class, methods, overriding, abstract, anonymous

I'm trying to override a abstract method using anonymous  class but it shows error like **Class A is not abstract** and **abstract method eat() not implemented**.Please Help me out

```
package javaapplication1;
abstract class D
{
    abstract void eat(); 
}
public class A extends D 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        D obj_d=new D(){

        @Override
         void eat()
              {
                   System.out.println("I'm eating!");
              }
    };
     obj_d.eat();
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove "extends D" from class A. Or implement `eat`in A. Creating an anonymous class will not make A implement it. It's a different class.

Comment: thanks now it gave me a clear understanding about anonymous classes